# Azure production environment and maintaining an sql database with migrations

Tags: azure, entity-framework-migrations

I've built a small web app that i'm thinking of deploying as a production site to azure. I've used a code first approach. I'm after some advice regarding maintaining an azure production db when it is possible/likely that some of my models might still change in the early phase of deployment depending on user testing, etc.

My workflow is probably not ideal. I've published to azure for testing and my data is stored in an sql db called project_db on azure.
But I keep making changes to my models on my local machine. And rather than using migrations - which i kind of get - but also find a bit difficult to handle, my workflow is that I change my model eg. adding a property - then I will go and delete my local database and then build my solution again. At least on my local machine that works without having to implement migrations. And i don't need any locally stored data and it just seeds again.

I was hoping to confirm that if I head down this path i'd have to do the same thing on azure. That is if i've changed my models locally, deleted my localdb and then built my solution again locally - I can't just publish to azure and expect my previously created sql project_db to work. I'd have to delete the azure project_db and create a new azure db that would be built based on my changed models.

And once i have changed my models on my machine (before having enabled migrations) - say i've added 10 new properties to IdentityModels.cs and i want to deploy to my existing project_db that already contains data...if I enable migrations at this point will it migrate to azure and maintain my data. Or do migrations have to be enabled from the beginning before the very first publishing of the db to azure?

I did try to publish to the azure project_db after having changed my models (incl IdentityModel.cs) on my local machine. I wasn't able to log in even though the AspNetUser table still contained the email addresses, etc. that had previoulsy been entered. I'm assuming that's an issue with my changed models having mismatched the azure AspNetUser table in project_db.

Thanks for the advice.